# How to regularize estimated probabilities in linear regression?

Tags: regression, regularization

I estimate a linear probability model of the form:

$
 E[y\mid X] = X\beta
$

where $y$ is a binary variable (hence, $E[y\mid X]= Pr(y=1\mid X)$) and $X$ a matrix coding a categorical variable by using dummies.How to regularize the estimated probabilities (i.e., $\hat\beta_j$ for some $j=1,2,...$ categories) to avoid unrealistic boundary cases such as an estimated probability of one or zero?

Comment: Change the link function from identity to logit.

Comment: I believe the logit link doesn't solve the issue when all the cases in the category are 0's or 1's.

Comment: If you mean Y=1 for all subjects in category i, I do not think there is regular method to restrict the estimate from boundary.

Comment: I was thinking something like what is suggested by Agresti & Caffo (2000) here: http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_caffo_2000.pdf

Comment: Or even a Bayesian approach using priors to regularize the estimates, as suggested by Gelman

Comment: If you just have one categorical variable, then you do not need the modeling. Just estimate the $\pi_i$ in Binomial($n_i,\pi_i$) and CI. You can get CI by exact method. http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/TraditionalBinomialCI.pdf, begin from page 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87440/discussion-between-mrb-and-user158565).

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about boundary cases, then you should switch to a logistic regression (or a more appropriate model for your data).

If you are still interested in regularization, glmnet is a package to compute various regularized coefficients for GLMs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you expand a little what kind of regularizations there are in the `glmnet` package?

Comment: They do lasso, ridge, and elastic net.